# SSH tunnel through a web browser

Tags: javascript, ssh, websocket, remote-access, tunnel

I know it can be done with some java applets, but I've been wondering if it is possible to do with javascript or other technologies, I guess there have to be something with WebSockets.

Here is what I want to achieve:

We have a remote device with an SSH client installed and the capability of receiving commands. I want to be able to open a web browser at a random client (desktop computer), open/start somehow an SSH server / endpoint, send a command to the remote device which will open a reverse SSH tunnel to the desktop computer so it could finally access the tunnel with a simple call like `http://localhost:port`.

Is that possible without JAVA + APPLETS (of course the desktop computer must not install any ssh server specifically).

Comment: How is SSH client "capable of receiving commands"? Is it some custom application peeking commands from the server?

Comment: The SSH client is not able to receive commands, they are received by the computer/system running the SSH client but not through SSH.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do you know socket.io? Maybe it's useful for what you want to do. You will need a server with nodejs witch can listen for client events and open a ssh or anything else.

http://socket.io/#how-to-use